# OCR and word reviewing

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract for my letter recognition project and currently the recognitions is quite good. The image processing part was done using OpenCv libraries.
The letters are hand written.But there are some problems when I used it to recognise the letter "O" and number "0". These letters are used in data areas as the fields that enter names. So names cannot have any numbers with it. And when we are using the the system of the data fields as date of birth it only contains numbers. So I'm willing to give restriction to the recognition system saying that the corresponding data fields have only numbers or the letters.

And also I'm willing to review the recognised letters with the possible words so we can improve the accuracy of the data. I'm willing to use the openCv libraries for this task. But I don't know what are the libraries that help for this task and what are the functionalities of those. So please can some one help me. Thank you.

Regards,
Thilanka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used Tesseract. However, [in the FAQ it says](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ)

### How do I recognise only digits?

```
TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

Presumably you could use the pattern of the FAQ entry to set it up so it only recognises letters or just digits appropriately.

If you have already tried this, can you give more details of why it doesn't work?